# excel vba macro stops / debugs on activecell.formula line

Tags: excel, vba

Seems some similar stuff out there, but i can't find one to match this. Anyone have any idea why this macro won't run? It's 3 lines - select cell, input formula, move to different cell. It stops at my activecell.formula line everytime - which is basically a big if statement, a cell divided by a cell on a certain sheet, depending on the name of a cell.

```
 Range("M11").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]/IF(R11C10=""Health Care"",'S5HLTH Index'!RC[-6],IF(R11C10=""Information Technology"",'S5INFT Index'!RC[-6],IF(R11C10=""Materials"",'S5MATR Index'!RC[-6],IF(R11C10=""Industrials"",'S5INDU Index'!RC[-6],IF(R11C10=""Real Estate"",'S5RLST Index'!RC[-6],IF(R11C10=""Communication Services"",'SPX Index'!RC[-6],IF(R11C10=""Consumer Discreationary"",'S5COND Index'!RC[-6],I" & "=""Utilities"",'S5UTIL Index'!RC[-6],IF(R11C10=""Energy"",'S5ENRS Index'!RC[-6],IF(R11C10=""Financials"",'S5FINL Index'!RC[-4],IF(R11C10=""Consumer Staples"",'S5CONS Index'!RC[-6])))))))))))"
Range("M12").Select
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Debug.Print your formula to the Immediate pane and try pasting it into a cell - you will get some hint as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This portion of your formula

...IF(R11C10=""Consumer Discreationary"",'S5COND Index'!RC[-6],I" & "=""Utilities"",'S5UTIL Index'!RC[-6],IF...

Instead of IF(condition, true, IF(condition....)

It looks like it is

IF(condition, true, false, ???, IF(......)